# Inserting JavaScript into a self-executing function

Tags: javascript, ajax, client-side

I help manage a Content Management System (CMS) that other programmers use to create content that includes JavaScript. Historically, we put the content into an iFrame so that it was contained; now it is a single-page client-side application and JavaScript is inserted into the same window.

The existing library of content was poorly developed, so I'm attempting to manage the potential for a muddled window object or memory leaks after several pages of content have loaded and/or viewed.

I was considering wrapping the JavaScript with a self-executing function or something similar that I would set to 'undefined' and delete ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817667/self-destructing-javascript-function-how-does-it-work)). The challenge is that I would have to inject the wrapper first, so I can't just use a straight ajax call for the script tag. Does that mean my only alternative is to append the wrapper to the JavaScript as a string and then use eval? I don't want to use that method, but it might be appropriate here.

For example, if the script .js file contains the following code:

```
var global = true;
```

If would end up as:

```
(function() {
  var global = true;
})();
```

In which it would no longer be global.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I just read your questions three times and I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you post more code examples (maybe an example where you actually use `eval`...just to show what your goal is)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare global variable in JS, you should not use `var` keyword:

```
global = true;
```

It creates a property on the `window` object which can be used everywhere.